# How do I swap Rails components with my own? How to swap Rails components in and out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, components, railtie

As far as I understand, what defines a Rails component/module is that it subclasses an own Railtie class from Rails::Railtie (the latter being an interface and being unable of being instantiated.)

How do the components/modules get loaded and how do I swap for example ActiveRecord with my own ORM-module?

Yours,

von Spotz

Comment: This is an extremely broad question where the answer would basically be a book about the ruby object model, how rails architecture works and the pros/cons of monkeypatching.

Comment: If you want to swap the ORM to for example Mongoid you usually remove line that requires the ActiveRecord railtie from `config/application.rb`. And remove any config settings relating to AR. 
You would probably get better answers if you actually describe what the goal is - not how you think you should get there.